# How do I get segment style button in SwiftUI

Tags: macos, swiftui

So in SwiftUI, macOS, I want individual buttons that can be turned on and off like check boxes but look like buttons, and they are interrelates, think like bit flags, and so I want them to touch like you can with `NSSegmentedControl`, it would seem to me you want use `Button` or `Toggle` with some modifier to group them, but I can't find it, `PickerStyle` seems to be exclusively radio options, which makes sense as SwiftUI seems to be more about describing the function, and then controlling how that is presented.

**Update to make it clearer**

It for regular expression options, I could do it with checkbox, but it doesn't look very good, it feels like there should be a method to change how the checkboxes are displayed, in this example I have the first three buttons enabled.
[image]

Comment: You're going to have to be a bit more descriptive. I don't entirely understand what you're looking for.

Comment: So you want a horizontal button section with multiple buttons, each of which has an on/off state independent of each other. Just like that example image there? What is the criteria? Can only one be enabled, multiple?

Comment: No, more than one can be enabled, a regex can be dot all. and ignore case for example, SegmentControl on SwiftUI are radio buttons, its a control that lets you select from one of multiple values mutually exclusively, I want it to work like check box, but not look like that as its ugly for horizontal layout

Comment: I think it got down voted because you effectively asked for a horizontal view of buttons. That wasn't clear in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is a simple custom solution:

```
struct Option: Hashable {
    let label: String
    var selected: Bool
}


struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var options: [Option] = [
        Option(label: "Dot All", selected: false),
        Option(label: "Extended", selected: false),
        Option(label: "Ignore Case", selected: false),
        Option(label: "Multi-line", selected: false),
    ]
    
    var body: some View {
        OptionPicker(options: $options)
    }
}


struct OptionPicker: View {
    
    @Binding var options: [Option]
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack(spacing: 0) {
            ForEach(options.indices, id: \.self) { i in
                
                Text(options[i].label)
                    .padding(.horizontal, 4)
                    .padding(5)
                    .background(options[i].selected ? .blue : .gray)
                
                    .onTapGesture {
                        options[i].selected.toggle()
                    }
                
                if i < options.count-1 {
                Divider()
                }
            }
        }
        .foregroundColor(.white)
        .cornerRadius(10)
        .frame(height: 32)
    }
}
```

[image]